# How do I Implement Multiple SharePoint Form Validations in PreSaveAction

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

So first, I know nothing about Javascript other than what I find on the web.

I have a SharePoint form and I'm trying to implement specific validations when a user presses "Save."

These are:

1. Two specific fields of the form can't be the same value.
2. The dropdown list value (which is a lookup column) cannot say "Select from list" which is the default option.

There's already a `PreSaveAction` that prevents it from being saved if there are no documents attached, which works perfectly.

However, when I try to add one of the additional validations (again based on what I find on the web) under the `PreSaveAction`, none of them work.

I have the form element names, but can't seem to get it to work.

Edit based on comment: The latest code I tried is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function PreSaveAction() {
if (document.getElementById('idAttachmentsRow').style.display=='none' )
 {
 alert('Please attach supporting documents.');
 return false ;
}
else {  return true;  }
}

   {
     if($("select[title='Vendor & Co Code'] option:selected").val() == '~Select Vendor from List')
     {
        alert("Please select vendor.")
        return false;
     }
    else
    {
    return true;
    }

  }
```

The document attachment part works on it own, but when I added the later, neither worked.

Comment: I would advice you to add some code of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances to get an answer and reduce the chances to have the question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not not correct.

Try script below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function PreSaveAction() {
            if (document.getElementById('idAttachmentsRow').style.display=='none' )
            {
                alert('Please attach supporting documents.');
                return false ;
            }
            if ($("select[title='Vendor & Co Code'] option:selected").val() == '~Select Vendor from List') {
                alert("Please select vendor.")
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Perfect! I had to make some changes to my portion (the title and value were actually incorrect) but when I did that with your changes, it worked.   Turns out I had too many brackets.    So now I'm trying to do a validation on 2 forms of the field so they can't equal - #1 in my question above.   Tried this code and it didn't work:

If(document.getElementByID(‘ProjectManager’).val == document.getElementbyID(‘GOA_x0020_Approver’).val
{
 Alert(“Project Manager and GOA Approver cannot be the same.”);
 Return false; 
}
The fields aren't text fields, but rather "People and Groups"

Comment: @wrios I'm not sure if you have already accepted his solution as the answer, but if not then you should as his solution solved your initial question. If you are having issues with another aspect then you should ask a new question or accept and continue the conversation here.

Comment: @Matt  thanks, I couldn't find how to accept an answer - I was looking for it.  I gave him a +1 but since I'm low rep it doesn't show, and somehow skipped right over the check mark.   My question though was a 2 part question from the outset but I only had space to type one code block.  So we answered #2, but #1 is still open.

Comment: @wrios  For #1 you would just do what you did for #2, only comparing the values of those fields. It's just another if-statement. As for the else part, you don't really need the else. You can just put `return true` at the very bottom and if no if-statement is used then it will default to returning true and saving.